# Python- Calling elements from a list returns wrong ones

Tags: python, list

from this list, from which I shuffle:

```
RotationSpeedArray = [4,6,8,10] #in Hz
random.shuffle(RotationSpeedArray)
```

I try to call it from one specific number at a time,

```
print RotationSpeedArray[0]
print RotationSpeedArray[1]
print RotationSpeedArray[2]
print RotationSpeedArray[3]
```

but whenever I do I get this:

```
#an actual empty space
[
6
,
```

The code from this is part is meant to draw a figure and rotate it. We want to do so a different speeds, so that's why we created a list from which it takes one of those rotation speeds and uses it. The figure actually moves for each trial at a different speed, so the process of taking one value at a time works. I just don't get why whenever I ask to show me each value of the list, it does this.

I hope this is sufficiently clear; please don't hesitate asking me any question.

Comment: Your code must be running differently than you're typing it... I got the following output 6, 8, 4, 10.  Do you have quotes around the entire RotationSpeedArray?  Also, you shouldn't capitalize that - it's not a class definition.

Comment: Based on your output, it looks as though you've enclosed the list in quotes.

Comment: somewhere in your code you transformed your array into a string and then printed that instead of the actual array. Check your code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having no problems.  Are you sure you're not surrounding converting your list to a string somewhere down the line??  It's treating RotationSpeedArray as a string, which is why I ask.

random.shuffle will throw a TypeError if you had put quotes around the list, so I'm assuming there is code you're not showing us somewhere past that which is converting it to a string?

```
import random
RotationSpeedArray = [4,6,8,10] #in Hz
random.shuffle(RotationSpeedArray)

# the problem is happening here


print(RotationSpeedArray[0])
print(RotationSpeedArray[1])
print(RotationSpeedArray[2])
print(RotationSpeedArray[3])

print(RotationSpeedArray)

# To demonstrate your particular issue, if we convert the list to a string
# we get the same problem you're having
StringArray = str(RotationSpeedArray)

print(StringArray[0])
print(StringArray[1])
print(StringArray[2])
print(StringArray[3])

print(StringArray)
```

Output:

```
10
6
4
8
[10, 6, 4, 8]
[
1
0
,
[10, 6, 4, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you said before, there's a lot more code. I further checked the script, and I set the variable to use it afterwards:

`exp.set("RotationSpeedArray", RotationSpeedArray)`

Does this influence the array itself?